# Classloader (and Guice) acting weird

Tags: java, classloader, guice

So I've got a failure to guice-bind a class to an object (in my guice module), code: `bind(MyClass.class).toInstance(myObject)`. Guice pukes out a `ClassNotFoundException`, refeering to one of the fields of `MyClass`. Since I'm running in an application server I was thinking that perhaps I could just change the thread context classloader?

So I tried using the classloader found in `myObject.getClass().getClassLoader()` and still I get `ClassNotFoundException`. How can that be? I even tried to evaluate this expression in debug (same result).

Comment: Can you post a stack trace as well as the code/class where the issue occurs?

Comment: I I'll see what I can do about a code-snippet - it's a cumbersome process to extract it. Some more digging on the object in question shows me alot of "LinkageError" and failures to cast object to the class - refeering to a custom AS "MultiparentClassLoader". Any leads on that?

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is a high probability that ClassNotFoundException has nothing to do with actual class not being found.

Without more information I'd say there is an uncaught exception being thrown inside one of the static initializer blocks of a class used by MyClass.

Check and recheck what is happening in the static initializers.

If you are not using WebSphere then by default the ClassLoaders inside your AS of choice should work just fine.